# Magento 2: How to call function in phtml file from parent block

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I have create a block which contains a phtml file.This .phtml file called other phtml file.

Please check code :

block name : `..\block\country.php`

This block has a template file, name : `country.phtml`
Code in this file

```
<?php
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml")->toHtml();
?>
```

As you seen `country.phtml` file call `state.phtml` file.

Now issue is, if I want to use any function of parent block `country.php` in `state.phtml` file then I am getting an error.

So please help me how can I called functions of parent block `country.php`

Thank you.

**If I set `state.phtml` in `country.phtml` like**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Namespace\Module\Block\Country")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml")->toHtml();
?>
```

Then Is it possible to call functions of `Country.php` in `State.phtml` file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this code you create this block and render it immediately, without adding it to the layout hierarchy. That means it doesn't have access to the parent block because *there is no parent*.

To create a block dynamically as child of the current block, use:

```
$child = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml");
$this->addChild('state', $child);
```

And to render it:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('state');
```

(I used "state" as alias here, but it can be anything else)

Now you have access to the parent from your state.phtml template, using `$this->getParentBlock()`

---

> **If I set `state.phtml` in `country.phtml` like**
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Namespace\Module\Block\Country")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml")->toHtml();
> ?>
> ```
>
> Then Is it possible to call functions of `Country.php` in
>   `State.phtml` file ?

If you insist, you can do it like this:

```
 echo $this->getLayout()
     ->createBlock("Namespace\Module\Block\Country")
     ->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml")
     ->setData('country_block', $this)
     ->toHtml();
```

And then, in `state.phtml`:

```
$this->getData('country_block')->METHOD_OF_COUNTRY_BLOCK();
```

Comment: I use this code but getting an error "Element with ID 'product.info.main_schedule_block5.state' is already defined."

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: Then the "state" alias is already used or the code is called twice. Try using a different alias, or if you use the code in a loop, append an incrementing number.

Comment: But for the sake of completeness, I added a solution for your updated question as well.

Comment: I try your updated answer.But it gives me blank page. I also delete  var folder and then try.

Comment: you have to replace `METHOD_OF_COUNTRY_BLOCK` with the method you want to call. Also check your PHP error logs when you get a blank page, to see what exactly the error was

Comment: Yes I used method name from block. And not getting any error in my log.  :(

Comment: Then you have either disabled logging or looking at the wrong logs. Please see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

You can easily access the parent block methods like:

```
$this->getParentBlock()->MethodName();
```

The `$this->getParentBlock()` will return the instance of Parent Block in child template file.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

- Create a custom block for your state template
- Make that block extend your country block
- This way you can use `$block->yourFunction()` easily

Don't forget to update your code:

```
<?php
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Namespace\Module\State")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::state.phtml")->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: there any other way to accomplish my query ? Because I have 4 - 5 files which is calling state.phtml file.