# Magento2 : How to get block file in phtml file

Tags: blocks, magento-2.1.7

To get block in magento1 we use `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_grid')->toHtml()`.

What is the similar function in magento2?

Comment: Are you referring to use block Function  in PHTML ?

Comment: No, I want to load grid `A grid block`, I did same in magento1. Is it possible to load grid in magento2 phtml file?

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109974/magento-2-how-to-call-function-in-phtml-file-from-parent-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in `Magento2` If your `Block` class extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

`$block->getLayout()->createBlock('something/something')->toHtml()`

If your `Block` class does not extend `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` then you can Inject the `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface` in your block `construct` and you can use use this pattern.